# Working with video and canvas element in Angular

Tags: angular, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm trying to get a stream and render it using drawImage as suggested in some of the Google developer tutorials.   I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

After hours I still can't figure out why so I thought I'd reach out for help.  My code attached...

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-scanner',
  templateUrl: './scanner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scanner.component.css']
})
export class ScannerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  @ViewChild('mycanvas') mycanvas: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('myvideo') myvideo: ElementRef;
  ctx;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.drawOnCanvas();
  }

  drawOnCanvas() {
    this.ctx = this.mycanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: true
      })
      .then(stream => {
        this.myvideo.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
        this.drawCanvas();
        //this.myvideo.nativeElement.play();
      });
  }

  drawCanvas() {
    this.mycanvas.nativeElement.width = this.myvideo.nativeElement.clientWidth;
    this.mycanvas.nativeElement.height = this.myvideo.nativeElement.clientHeight;
    this.ctx.drawImage(
      this.myvideo.nativeElement.srcObject,
      0,
      0,
      this.mycanvas.nativeElement.width,
      this.mycanvas.nativeElement.height
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas #mycanvas id="mycanvasid"></canvas>
  <video #myvideo></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of running `drawOnCanvas` in `ngOnInit`, try it in [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#ngAfterViewInit). The view and elements will not be ready when `ngOnInit` fires.

Comment: Ya sorry I just updated the code (had an old copy in there before I pasted it)  I've actually tried the ngAfterViewInit thing and was (and am) still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not starting your stream it seems...

As I am using it

html

```
  <div id="inner_video" >
      <video #video id="video" autoplay></video>
  </div>

  <canvas #canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768">canvas</canvas>
```

ts

```
 @ViewChild("video")
  public video: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild("canvas")
  public canvas: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
          this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
          this.video.nativeElement.play();
      });
    }
  }
```

capture code

```
 capture(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var context = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.video.nativeElement, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
    var picture: any = this.canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL("image/png");
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.   I had been starting the stream previously but commented it out.  I just put it back in (actually refactored the code to be exactly what you have above) but I get the following error when I try to run the drawCanvas method...  Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type... I tried pulling the calling of that method out into a 'button' just to see if it was an issue with some of the elements not having time to load but I still get the same error.

Comment: shouldn;t the drawCanvas not be after you play statement?  Also this, getContext need to be the same, after  (anyway, I guess you did this as you said "refactor")

Comment: When I responded I was only seeing a small part of your response (I think I may have responded while you were still editing the code snippet!  I'm now playing with your full code response, thanks so much for taking the time to respond.  Will get back with results shortly.

Comment: Also note that it should be  `this.myvideo.nativeElement` and not `this.myvideo.nativeElement.srcObject`